# Spring Scheduled Tasks: Fixed Rate and Cron

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I am implementing scheduled tasks using spring. I have a fixed rate task which runs every 30 minutes. I would like to configure it run every 30 min during 9 - 5, mon - fri. Please suggest me a way to do this.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you trying to roll your own or are you using Quartz?

Answer (score 4):

Simple. Fixed rate:

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import static org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_MINUTE;

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 30 * MILLIS_PER_MINUTE)
```

CRON expression (not tested, please fix if incorrect):

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* 0,30 9-17 * * MON-FRI")
```

#### See also:

- [25.5.1 The @Scheduled Annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled)